# Is there a way to treat an inline picture (a link rendered as an image) as one character in org table?

Tags: org-table, images

Is there a way to treat an inline picture (a link rendered as an image) as one character in org table?

When I align an org table that has a small image in a field, the alignment gets really messy, since the link of that tiny picture is actually really long.

Let's say the "o" below is a tiny picture of an apple. The alignment gets weird like this:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------+-------|
| o | apple |
|                                                                |       |
```